# Use image from an image that contains multiple images!

Tags: image, visual-studio-2010, icons

So looking in the image file repository that comes with vs 2010, I can see lots of images that contain multiple images...say of different sizes.

How do I use that file to display one of the smaller images that is contained in the file?

Hope that makes sense!! I didn't have much luck with google...probably because I didn't know what to ask!!

Thx

Answer (score 1):

try looking at image sprites in css http://stylemeltdown.com/2007/10/22/image-sprite-navigation-with-css/

Comment: I'm not sure that is exactly what I am looking for, but then I guess it could be!